# Polymer: how to replace tag name depend on attribute?

Tags: polymer

I have such template

```
<template>
    <button class="y-button" id="el" disabled?="{{disabled !== undefined}}">
        <span class="y-button__text"><content></content></span>
    </button>
</template>
```

How to change tag name  to another (e.g. `<a>`) depend on some attribute, e.g.
`<my-button url="http://example.org"></my-button>`?

I tried

```
<template>
  <{{tagName}}></{{tagName}}>
</template>
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you trying to dynamically create elements based on the model? If so you can simply handle it with the element's javascript. Let me know with some more specifics, so I can assist you better.

Comment: I have a big declared tag in template: button several handlers, classes with data binding. Now i need to dynamically change tag name  <button> to <a> depend on attribute url with saving handlers and classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `injectBoundHTML`:

```
var tag = 'x-el';
var html = '<' + tag + ' item="{{item}}"></' + tag + '>';
this.injectBoundHTML(html, this.$.container);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="x-el" attributes="item" noscript>
  <template>
    {{item.name}}
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        this.item = {name: 'John Smith'};
        
        var tag = 'x-el';
        var html = '<' + tag + ' item="{{item}}"></' + tag + '>';
        this.injectBoundHTML(html, this.$.container);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with data binding. Binding expressions are only allowed in the text content of a tag or in an attribute value:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#node-bindings

You also can't insert entire tags using data binding, because the contents of data binding expressions are HTML escaped before being inserted. See:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#expression-syntax

"You can’t insert HTML using expressions. To avoid XSS issues, the output of an expression is HTML escaped before being inserted as the value of the binding."

If you just have two possible tags, you can use the conditional template syntax:

```
<template if="{{condition}}">
  <tagOne></tagOne>
</template>
<template if="{{! condition}}">
  <tagTwo></tagTwo>
</template>
```

For more complicated cases, you might want to use JavaScript and innerHTML as suggested by @skmvasu. If you need data bindings to be active *inside* the inserted HTML, you can use the injectBoundHTML method:

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#boundhtml